# Apache Ignite SQL performance COUNT vs SELECT

Tags: java, sql, ignite

I have a Ignite server with a persistent cache which I query with SQL. I'm observing different performances which I can't explain:

1. Using SQL COUNT:

   ```
        String         sql   = "SELECT COUNT(*) AS NUM FROM " + cacheName + " " + sqlParam;
        SqlFieldsQuery query = new SqlFieldsQuery(sql);
        query.setArgs(args);

        FieldsQueryCursor<List<?>> cursor = cache.query(query);
        resultCount = cursor.getAll().get(0).get(0);
   ```
2. Using SQL SELECT:

   ```
        String         sql   = "SELECT _key, _val FROM " + cacheName + " " + sqlParam;
        SqlFieldsQuery query = new SqlFieldsQuery(sql);
        query.setArgs(args);

        FieldsQueryCursor<List<?>> cursor = cache.query(query);
        resultCount = cursor.getAll().size();
   ```

With the same sqlParam and on the same cache with 160K entries using #1 statement takes roughly 120ms. While #2 statement takes only 5ms.

I wonder why COUNT is significantly slower? Shouldn't this be more efficient compared to getting the whole list of cache objects in a list and then return the list size?

Comment: What is sqlParam in your case? could you repeat query 10 times to eliminate warm up effects.

Comment: @PavelVinokurov sqlParam is `jobId=?` for SQL #1 and `jobId=? LIMIT 1000` for SQL #2.

Answer (score 0):

`count()` has to read the entire table before it can return one row.

The second query can start returning rows as it is reading the table.

I am guessing that you are measuring the time to the *first* row, not the time to the *last* row.  I would expect the second to be slower overall, because of the overhead of reading more than one row.

Comment: Using getAll() on the result cursor loads all items into the list, which I then use with size(). So I guess it has to go the the last row. However, I now realize I'm using "LIMIT" in my sql statement. If I'm setting this to higher value the performance difference changes in favor of #1.

Comment: @DonTequila . . . Interesting.  The `limit` is doing mechanistically what I thought was happening under the hood.

Comment: I've further played with limit and it turns out that SQL #1 always constant duration, regardless of the value of limit. SQL #2 is faster than SQL #1 on small limit value but takes longer the higher I set limit. This kind of makes sense.

Comment: @DonTequila . . . The `limit` makes no sense on a `count()` query.  An aggregate query with no `group by` always returns exactly one row.

Comment: Sorry, my fault. `limit` is not used for the count() query. I just double checked this.